# Rake test equivalent for ActionMailer::TestHelper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, actionmailer

We have recently migrated from sending emails with `deliver_now` to `deliver_later`. So that queued emails aren't lost when the system restarts, we implement this with Sidekiq.

When we used `deliver_now`, our Rake tests could test the sending of an email with

```
assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count
```

For Rspec there is the `assert_enqueued_emails` method to test whether or not emails are queued.  Is there an equivalent for Rake test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, once I knew what to do:

1. Add the line `include ActionMailer::TestHelper` to the start of the test file
2. Execute the method `perform_enqueued_jobs` after all emails were queued.

After that, all the old tests worked fine.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html#method-i-perform_enqueued_jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `have_enqueued_mail` matcher ([documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/5-1/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-mail-matcher)). Then your spec would use something like the following.

`have_enqueued_mail(MyMailer, :my_particular_email).once`

Comment: This appears to be for Rspec, not Rake Test. Is there some method mapping or model inclusion that I am not seeing?